# Automating my job in .bat commands

Tags: batch-file, wmi, rename

This set of commands does not run through cleanly. It renames properly but doesn't join the domain or add the user to the localgroup administrators.

```
@echo off
SET /P compName=Name of the computer:%=%
SET /P duName=Computer User:%=%
SET /P adminUserName=Admin UserName:%=%
SET /P adminPassword=Admin Password:%=%
echo If the Above information was entered incorrectly or is incorrect please exit this application now.
PAUSE
CLS

echo Renaming the computer %compName%.
wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM WHERE Name="%ComputerName%" CALL Rename Name="%compName%" Password=null UserName=null

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul

echo Error Level: %errorlevel%
echo Joining the computer to the Doamin.net Domain.
wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM WHERE Name="%COMPUTERNAME%" CALL JoinDomainOrWorkgroup FJoinOptions=1 Name="Domain.net" UserName="%adminUserName%" Password="%adminPassword%"
echo Error Level: %errorlevel%

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul

echo Adding %duName% to the Administrator's group.
net LOCALGROUP Administrators /ADD %duName%
echo Error Level: %errorlevel%

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul

echo Restarting computer...
Shutdown /R /c "Restarting computer and applying changes."
```

But if I replace the Ping commands with PAUSE it does go cleanly through. Problem is that I want it automated and I don't want to use a different coding language. I think the problem lies with the WMIC already being used for the rename and the PAUSE releases it and then it get's reinitialized again for the domain then of course the add to administrators group fails since it's always going to be a domain account, but again I don't know for sure. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I changed FJoinOptions = 3; and now it adds the user to local admins after joining domain but does not rename the computer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it will be much easier if you use powershell instead of bat file. To add computer to domain you can use examples from http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/domain-join-using-powershell-v2-0-part-i/. To add user to local admin group üyou can use this one http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-AD-UserGroup-to-Local-fe5e9239

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing `wmic` to `start /wait "" wmic` and remove the PINGs completely.

Comment: Same treatment for the `net` command? Or try replacing the `PING`s with `timeout /t 5` where the numeric is the timeout period in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use

```
ping -n 1 1.1.1.1 > Nul
```

and just change -n 1 to however many seconds you want to wait. The options should be before the target but that's just a matter of semantics

If you think the WMIC lines are causing the issue, replace them with NETDOM commands. It's much easier to use.

Comment: boss said something about being the man and we need to keep the users down. I used netdom before and it gave me the same issue.